# Is safe enough that Encryption and decryption using javascript 

Tags: javascript, save, encryption

this is  the javascript library:  [jsencryption.js](http://www.vincentcheung.ca/jsencryption/examples.html)

i want to use it to :

1. Encryption  the data  of users in my site ,and then send to the database server .
2. send the Encrypted data from database to browser-client , the user put the `key`, and

then show the raw data .

3 . the databse not save the key , so it is more safe .

i want to know  the way is or not safe enough ,  what about http://www.passpack.com/en/home/

and How  the `passpack.com` save the password .

thanks

Comment: Who do you want to hide the data from? It sounds like you want to hide it from yourself (the server admin) and any potential eavesdroppers and only allow the user access to the data using his key?

Comment: Is it safe enough to rely on Javascript alone? No. Javascript can be turned off.
You will have to rely on a server side implementation.

Comment: @Russell I don't think that's a valid argument. If javascript is turned off, the sent data will be in the wrong format (or not even sent at all) and the server will not respond.

Comment: Your security is only as safe as your cypher/keys.  If the keys are available to anyone, then you've lost your security.  With public/private key cyphers, this is true of the private keys.

Comment: Why do you want to reimplement ssl/https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jsencryption.js library you link to [claims the following](http://www.vincentcheung.ca/jsencryption/features.html)

- The encryption used is 256-bit AES, the standard used by the US Government
- Unlike regular password protection, everything is done locally in the browser using JavaScript, so your unencrypted information is never on the internet, not even on the server!
- The encrypted text is safe as long as you keep the key secret. Do not lose the key. If you do, no one can help you!

So, yes, if the password is strong enough this looks to be very secure (unless someone messes with the user's browser or computer, think keylogger or malicious firefox plugin or the site itself undermining the script).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are several JavaScript AES-256 encryption implementations around, including:

- http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html
- http://people.eku.edu/styere/Encrypt/JS-AES.html
- http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/aes/aes-test.htm
- http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes/

Before you use any of these, you should test them with the AES test vectors. The implementation from `hanewin.net` [claims to do so][1].

[1]:     - http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/aes/aes.htm

However, I have some questions about your underlying design. What's your threat model? Lots of people have looked at having encryption/decryption done in the browser. But that's not necessarily more secure, as if somebody breaks in to the server they can booby-trap the browser's JavaScript. Certainly this will keep you protected against somebody compromising your database server and downloading the tables, but server-side encryption would do that as well. And the big advantage of server-side encryption is that you can use trusted modules like OpenSSL and not have to worry about the quality of the JavaScript implementations.